# dbDelta not adding additional columns in plugin database update

Tags: plugins, database, mysql, dbdelta

I'm trying to update my database by adding an extra column field. However, dBdelta does not seem to be doing its job. I'm not sure what am I doing wrong.

```
<?php

function installer(){
    include('installer.php');
}
register_activation_hook( __file__, 'installer' ); //executes installer php when installing plugin to create new database

//database update checkdate
function myplugin_update_db_check() {
    global $xenonresult_db_version;
    if ( get_site_option( 'xenonresult_db_version' ) != $xenonresult_db_version ) {
        installer();
    }
}
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'myplugin_update_db_check' );
```

Here is the installer.php

```
<?php
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "xenonresult";
    $xenonresult_db_version = '1.1';
    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

    if ( $wpdb->get_var( "SHOW TABLES LIKE '{$table_name}'" ) != $table_name ) {
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table_name (
        `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `roll_number` int(11) NOT NULL,
        `student_name` text NOT NULL,
        `father_name` text NOT NULL,
        `obj_marks` int(9) NOT NULL,
        `sub_marks` int(9) NOT NULL,
        `result` text NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
        )    $charset_collate;";
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
        dbDelta( $sql );
        add_option( "xenonresult_db_version", $xenonresult_db_version );
    }

global $wpdb;
$installed_ver = get_option( "xenonresult_db_version" );
if ( $installed_ver != $xenonresult_db_version ) {

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'xenonresult';

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table_name (
        `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `roll_number` int(11) NOT NULL,
        `student_name` text NOT NULL,
        `father_name` text NOT NULL,
        `obj_marks` int(9) NOT NULL,
        `sub_marks` int(9) NOT NULL,
        `result` text NOT NULL,
        `mobile` varchar NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
        )    $charset_collate;";
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
        dbDelta( $sql );

    update_option( "xenonresult_db_version", $xenonresult_db_version );
}
?>
```

My default version is 1.0. In 1.1, I'm trying to add mobile column in my database.

Answer (score 2):

After trial and error, here is the code that works:

```
function installer(){
    include('installer.php');
}
register_activation_hook( __file__, 'installer' ); //executes installer php when installing plugin to create new database

//database update checkdate
function myplugin_update_db_check() {
    global $xenon_result_db_version;
    if ( get_option( 'xenon_result_db_version' ) != $xenon_result_db_version ) {
        installer();
    }
}

add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'myplugin_update_db_check' );
```

The installer.php looks somewhat like this:

```
<?php
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "xenon_result";
    $xenon_result_db_version = '1.2';
    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
    if ( $wpdb->get_var( "SHOW TABLES LIKE '{$table_name}'" ) != $table_name ) {
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
        `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `roll_number` int(11) NOT NULL,
        `student_name` text NOT NULL,
        `father_name` text NOT NULL,
        `mobile` varchar(55) NOT NULL,
        `obj_marks` int(9) NOT NULL,
        `sub_marks` int(9) NOT NULL,
        `total_marks` int(9) NOT NULL,
        `result` text NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
        )    $charset_collate;";
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
        dbDelta( $sql );
        add_option( "xenon_result_db_version", $xenon_result_db_version );
}
if ( get_option( 'xenon_result_db_version' ) != $xenon_result_db_version ){
$sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
        `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `roll_number` int(11) NOT NULL,
        `student_name` text NOT NULL,
        `father_name` text NOT NULL,
        `mobile` varchar(55) NOT NULL,
        `obj_marks` int(9) NOT NULL,
        `sub_marks` int(9) NOT NULL,
        `total_marks` int(9) NOT NULL,
        `result` text NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
        )    $charset_collate;";
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
        dbDelta( $sql );
        update_option( "xenon_result_db_version", $xenon_result_db_version );
}
?>
```